# What is the probability that three randomly chosen vertices of a regular 100-gon inscribed in a circle form a right angled triangle?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A regular polygon with $100$ sides is inscribed in a circle. What is the probability that three randomly chosen vertices of this polygon form a right angled triangle?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I think you can "fix" a vertex and workout some condition for the other two.

Answer (score 4):

There are $100\choose 3$ possible choices. There are $50\cdot 98$ way to pick a diagonal that is a diameter of the circumscribed circle and a point off the diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

> An inscribed triangle is a right triangle if its largest side is a diameter of the circle.
>   If the vertices of the regular $100$-gon are numbered $0$ through $99$ then a diameter connects
>   vertices whose numbers differ by $50$.
>   Without loss of generality we may choose to label the first vertex chosen as $0$.
>   Given two numbers $x$ and $y$ selected uniformly, randomly, without replacement from $1$-$99$
>   we seek the probability that either number is $50$, or that $\lvert x-y\rvert = 50$.
>   Note that these are disjoint events they cannot both be true.

I will end at this point in case this is an unlabeled homework assignment.
The rest is rather straightforward.